# Does IE9 keep the "Compatibility View" button?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

Is the "Compatibility View" button part of IE9?

If Internet Explorer 9 were to take a different approach to "compatibility" it would be relevant and helpful in the maintenance of legacy sites.

Comment: It sounds like only a demo was shown today, there's no way to know yet. Also, this isn't a programming question.

Comment: What is certain is that you will have some users still using IE6.

Comment: Too true Robert, it makes web development hurt so much. Lucky for javascript wrappers like jquery helps solve some of the hurt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and additionally it supports IE7 or IE8 compat mode in developer tools F12

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft is [about 3 weeks into the project](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2356083,00.asp). I guess it is too early to tell. If you want to vote on features, visit http://connect.microsoft.com/IE.

Comment: Feature - Include a FirefoxTab!

Answer (score 2):

The Platform Preview released now doesn't have a ‘compatibility view’ button yet — or any other buttons to speak of, as it's almost completely missing its UI — but it's clear that ‘compatibility view’ is here to stay:

> The Platform Preview Build will use the IE8 Compatibility View Settings including the  Compatibility View List. This means that if you’ve chosen to use the Compatibility View List in IE8, some high traffic websites will run in the IE7 Document Mode by default.

Quirks Mode has now been named ‘IE5 Document Mode’ in the interface, so you get to choose a browser quirkset from the menu for anything between IE5 and IE9 *except* IE6. Looks like Microsoft are stuck reproducing the bugs of every former version of IE into every future version from now on... that's the foot-shooting joy of OS integration I suppose.

Comment: The main cause is IE stagnating after they added DOCTYPE switching in IE6. OS integration just make it worse.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, yes.  It's in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question in SuperUser.com and it was closed as subjective and argumentative, except mine specifically asked whether it was being based on WebKit.

Given the fact that they have already greatly surpassed their previous values for compliance, I think they might have their sights set on that first.

I'm worried because I maintain a legacy app that will die without quirks mode myself.

Comment: Can it not be updated/upgraded to be compatible with a valid Doctype?

Comment: @ricebowl : In short : yes. Anything can be, given enough time and money. Long answer: the time and money aspects are hard to justify to our higher ups. BUT the potential good news is that if IE9 does not allow quirks mode, we have a drop-dead absolute MUST DO NOW deadline for updating our entire 50,000+ line front-end.